# Execute Script on Partial View

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following script in my Main View which works great to create cascading dropdownlists.  However, I cannot get it to execute on the partial view after it is loaded.  From what I have read online, it seems that  I need some sort of Ajax call in the partial view (which I am completely clueless on how to write).  Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#SelectedCollateralClass").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var ddlTypes = $("#SelectedCollateralType");
            var typesProgress = $("#types-loading-progress");
            typesProgress.show();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetCollateralTypesByClass"))",
                data: { "CollateralClassId": selectedItem },
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlTypes.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        ddlTypes.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
                    });
                    typesProgress.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve types.');
                    typesProgress.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My Main View is:

```
@model CollateralRowViewModel

<div class="APPLICATION">

    @*@Html.Partial("_SideBarView.cshtml");
    @Html.Partial("_CommentsView.cshtml");*@

    <!-- Content ======================================================================================-->

    <div class="container row">
        @using (@Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="col-xs-16">
                <div class="hr">
                    <h3 class="inline-block"> Collateral</h3>
                    <a class="icon-add"></a>
                </div>
                <table class="dataentry">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollateralClass)</th>
                            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollateralType)</th>
                            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)</th>
                            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.MarketValue)</th>
                            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PriorLiens)</th>
                            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdvanceRate)</th>
                            <th>@Html.Label("Grantor (if not Borrower)")</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="inputROW">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCollateralClass, Model.CollateralClass)
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="inputROW">
                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedCollateralType, Model.CollateralType)
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="inputROW">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="inputROW">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MarketValue)
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="inputROW">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PriorLiens)
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="inputROW">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdvanceRate)
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span class="inputROW Smargin_bottom">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GrantorFirstName)
                                </span>
                                <span class="inputROW">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GrantorMiddleName)
                                </span>
                                <span class="inputROW">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GrantorLastName)
                                </span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="minusRow">
                                <a class="btn btn-danger icon-subtract sm btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="remove(this)"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <div>
                    <input id="addBtn" type="button" value="Add New Collateral" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div> <!-- end container -->


    <footer id="APPfooter">
        <div class="pagination centerF">
            <ul>
                <li class="previous"><a href="#" class="icon-arrow-01"></a></li>
                <li class="next"><a href="#" class="icon-arrow-01"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div><!-- end page content container-->


<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function () {
            $('.default').dropkick();
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });
</script>
<script>
    $("#addBtn").on("click", function () {

        $.get('@Url.Action("AddNewRow")', function (data) {
            $("table").append(data);
        });

    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    $(function () {
        $("#SelectedCollateralClass").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var ddlTypes = $("#SelectedCollateralType");
            var typesProgress = $("#types-loading-progress");
            typesProgress.show();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetCollateralTypesByClass"))",
                data: { "CollateralClassId": selectedItem },
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlTypes.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        ddlTypes.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
                    });
                    typesProgress.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve types.');
                    typesProgress.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    }));
</script>
```

My partial looks like:

```
@model CollateralRowViewModel

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="inputROW">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedCollateralClass, Model.CollateralClass)
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="inputROW">
                           @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.SelectedCollateralType, Model.CollateralType)
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="inputROW">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Description)
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="inputROW">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.MarketValue)
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="inputROW">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.PriorLiens)
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="inputROW">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.AdvanceRate)
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="inputROW Smargin_bottom">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.GrantorFirstName)
                        </span>
                        <span class="inputROW">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.GrantorMiddleName)
                        </span>
                        <span class="inputROW">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.GrantorLastName)
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="minusRow">
                        <a class="btn btn-danger icon-subtract sm btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="remove(this)"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

The Controller Action is:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetCollateralTypesByClass(Guid collateralClassId)
    {
        var collateralServiceProxy = base.ServiceProvider.CollateralServiceProxy;
        var collateralTypes = await collateralServiceProxy.GetCollateralTypesByCollateralClassIdAsync(collateralClassId);

        var selectCollateraltypes = (from t in collateralTypes
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         id = t.Id.ToString(),
                                         name = t.Name
                                     }).ToList();

        return Json(selectCollateraltypes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The Partial is being called by a button "Add New" as follows:

```
<script>
    $("#addBtn").on("click", function () {

        $.get('@Url.Action("AddNewRow")', function (data) {
            $("table").append(data);
        });

    });
</script>
```

The Controller for the button is :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("CreateRow")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddNewRow()
{
    var collateralClasses = await GetCollateralClasses();
    var collateralTypes = await GetCollateralTypes();

    var model = new CollateralRowViewModel();

    model.CollateralClass.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please Select-", Value = "-1" });
    foreach (var _class in collateralClasses)
    {
        model.CollateralClass.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = _class.Value.ToString(),
            Text = _class.Text.ToString()
        });
    }

    model.CollateralType.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "-Please Select-", Value = "-1" });
    foreach (var type in collateralTypes)
    {
        model.CollateralType.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = type.Value.ToString(),
            Text = type.Text.ToString()
        });
    }
    return PartialView("_newCollateralRow", model);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to embed this code into your partial view or are you having problems with this script after the partial html loads?

Comment: I need it to work on the dropdownlists in the partial as well as in the main.  Currently, it only works in the main.

Comment: What does the main view and partial view look like?

Comment: Ok, some things to clean up: 1) You only need one document ready on the page `$(document).ready()` OR `$(function(){})` -- Then place all of your event handlers inside it. 2) The element ids need to be unique -- They way you are using the HtmlHelper means you get duplicate ids. Check your rendered html. 3) Given that the ids must be unique you may need to rethink how you use your view model in nested views and/or choose a different selector to trigger your javascript.

Comment: Where is your partial actually being called in your main view? It looks like you just have the contents of the partial embedded directly in the main view.

Comment: Jasen - I don't understand your explanation regarding the HtmlHelper as I am NEW to all of this.  I don't what ids you are talking about.

Comment: Chris - the partial just appends a new row to the table.

Comment: The `@Html` is the [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx). Look at the html for the rendered page and search for `id="SelectedCollateralClass"` -- the id values must be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.  All I needed to do was to add new{@class = "ddlClass'} and new {@class = "ddlType"} to the Partial.  Then I just copied the script to the Partial and changed the references from referencing the Id to referencing the new classes as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $(".ddlClass").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var ddlTypes = $(".ddlType");
            var typesProgress = $("#types-loading-progress");
            typesProgress.show();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetCollateralTypesByClass"))",
                data: { "CollateralClassId": selectedItem },
                success: function (data) {
                    ddlTypes.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                        ddlTypes.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
                    });
                    typesProgress.hide();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve types.');
                    typesProgress.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope this helps someone else!